# How to show alert message onclick after hiding the button using Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to display alert message on click **after** hiding the same button that is clicked?

This is my code :

```
$('.inner').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
    alert('what the heck');
});
```

Where **inner** would be the class of a button

Comment: Can you post some code that you already test

Comment: `alert();` at the end of your already existing code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
        alert("My message");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps. Now can we make this code shorter in any possible way?

Comment: I don't know any way of making it shorter, sorry.